# Good Entity Framework Tutorial

Tags: entity-framework-4

I wonder if anyone can point me towards a good online tutorial for Entity Framework (code first and database first).  I'm interested in learning the theory as I've been using EF for some time now but realise I don't know all the ins and outs.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_nf=3&tok=lRBBbWWDpqwlkclfNk5iJw&pq=fastest%20way%20to%20read%20large%20xml%20c%23&cp=19&gs_id=6a&xhr=t&q=entity+framework+tutorial&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=entity+framework+tu&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1c8794bdb2a7f36&bpcl=35277026&biw=1311&bih=619

Comment: There are some good ones here: https://learninglineapp.com/schedule. They are online courses, but the first hour of each is free and there are several on EF and LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This (http://entityframeworktutorial.net/default.aspx) covers the basics fairly well, but my suggestion would be to go the dead tree route and grab a copy of Julia Lerman's '*Programming Entity Framework (2nd ed)*'

Comment: I just bought the book.  It doesn't have much about Code First.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the best ones are [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Find?highlight=true&searchTerm=entity%20framework) videos on Entity Framework. You ought to take a look at them. They are not free though.
Hope it helps

Comment: There are multiple video lectures available makes difficult to select the exact one for newbie. Please point out the basic one and suggest the road map. Thank you.